# an efficient javascript split function to save bytes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to minify my javascript code as much as possible.

What I have 14 times is code like this:

o.split('x');

where o is the object name and x is the delimiter.

To cut code size down, I created this function:

```
function X(o,d){return o.split(d)}
```

This allows me to call the same split function like this:

```
X(o,'x');
```

Each function call saves me about 3 bytes per call. After the changes, I saved about 20 bytes.

Now what I want to do is convert the second parameter into a number that changes into the delimiter inside the function. I'm using up to 5 different delimiters. I'm not sure if this can be done since I want to support internet explorer 7.

Here's my thoughts on how I would modify the function but I'm not sure which is compatible with every browser new and old including Internet explorer 7.

Idea 1:

```
function X(o,d){var x=[';','.','=',' ','+'];return o.split(x[d])}
```

Idea 2:

```
function X(o,d){var x=';.= +';return o.split(x[d])}
```

Idea 3 (probably doesn't execute but it would allow me to save tons of bytes):

```
function X(o,d){return o.split(';.= +'[d])}
```

Idea 4 (same as idea 3):

```
function X(o,d){return o.split(';.= +'.substr(d,1))}
```

I'm just trying to condense the function and make it work for everyone.

The basic idea I'm trying to achieve is that I want a catalog of delimiters in my function that I can choose using a number as the second parameter of the function. The first parameter of the same function is the string that is to be split.

How can I properly write my function with the fewest lines of code possible? or do I have to resort to using a single-quoted character as my second parameter?

Comment: consider http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you consider passing a single-quoted character a bad idea? It would be more compact and better from the design prospective as it doesn't require user of the function to know the internal representation of the function (i.e. index of the required delimiter in the function).

Comment: Why don't you just use one of the existing Javascript minifiers?

Comment: @MokonaModoki He's trying to save 2 bytes in the source code for every time he calls `X()`.

Comment: Why do you think #3 won't execute? Did you try it? You can also use `[';','.','=',' ','+'][d]`

Comment: Your code is not likely any smaller than the original when served gzipped.

Comment: *"The basic idea... I want a catalog of delimiters in my function that I can choose using a number as the second parameter of the function."* - What a maintenance nightmare you are creating for yourself.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Golfing is explicitly off-topic on Code Review. Please read the [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making such suggestions.

Comment: I'm gonna fire up the real Internet explorer 7 along with a host of other browsers later tonight and experiment with my ideas and see what I can come up with.